# filtering database using select

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to filter my database using 2 select option() and () what I want is when the user load the page they can see database result organized in a table, when they choose the the select (drop down list) the table is filtered, they can choose one of the select (drop down list) or both for optimum result. so how can I adjust my code to work as I want it to ? I'm using oracle hr database but I keep getting this error: Undefined index , can some one tell me why?

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form  action="emp.php" method="post" name="Form2" id="Form2">
<select  id="officecode" name="officecode">
  <option value="">Select an officeCode:</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="reportsTo" name="reportsTo" >
  <option value="">reports To:</option>
  <option value="1143">1143</option>
  <option value="1102">1102</option>
  <option value="1108">1108</option>
  <option value="1056">1056</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="result"><b>
<?php include "emp.php"; ?>
</b></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var office = $("#officecode");
    var report = $("#reportsTo");
    the_office.change(function(){
        var the_selected_office = $(this).val();
        self.location = "emp.php?off="+the_selected_office+"&rep=";
    });
    the_report.change(function(){
        var the_selected_report = $(this).val();
        self.location = "emp.php?off=&rep="+the_selected_report+";
    });
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

emp.php

```
<?php
$office = $_POST["off"];
$report = $_POST["rep"];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "classicmodels";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql="SELECT * FROM employees WHERE reportsTo= '".$office."' AND reportsTo= '".$report."' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Employee Number</th>
  <th>Extension</th>
</tr>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['employeeNumber'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['extension'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're telling it to find the employees with different values for reportsTo at the same time, that's physically impossible :). So it's either you wanted to use different columns in your query to match against the values of $office and $report or.... use an OR statement instead of the AND?

Comment: ¿How is employees table?

Comment: @Filip my employee table has the following attributes : employeeNumber lastName firstName extension officeCode email jobTitle , so I don't think the query is the problem , I think for some reason It doesn't recognize $office and $report values because when I echo the values I get the same error : Undefined index, thank you for yuor time

Comment: @Cuchu my employee table has the following attributes : employeeNumber lastName firstName extension officeCode email jobTitle , thank you

Comment: @Glory but you are using the 'reportsTo' column to filter against in your SQL query and 'reportsTo' is not part of your table schema. How is that not a SQL problem :)?

Comment: Also please make sure you have actual input values from the submited form or else just set to values to an inexistent value, say 0?                          $office = isset($_POST['off']) ? $_POST['off'] : 0;
$report = isset($_POST['rep']) ? $_POST['rep'] : 0;

Comment: so, what is reportsTo? Exist another table, reportsTo reference to employe or another thin? The moment, try:
$office = isset($_POST['off']) ? $office = "officeCode={$_POST['off']}" : $office = "1";
$sql="SELECT * FROM employees WHERE {$office};";

Comment: @Filip I'm so sorry I didn't mention that 'reportsTo' is in my employee table , I add the line:   $office = isset($_POST['off']);
  $report =  isset($_POST['rep']); now I have no data, is it because the value is not passed to by $_POST['off'] ? and do you know how to fix it? thank you

Comment: @Cuchu it is an attribute I didn't mention I'm sorry about that, I tried what you said and go this error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object, thank you

Comment: try mysql_fetch_array

Comment: I doesn't read the passed values , why? did something wrong in the javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: Two  points, i comment database connect and the sql(for my) require join to other table, because your data or concept is wrong. In this case, the POST es empty, not same POST and GET, test code and see.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var office = $("#officecode");
    var report = $("#reportsTo");

    $("#officecode").change(function(){
        var the_selected_office = $(this).val();
        self.location = "index.php?off="+the_selected_office+"&rep=";
    });

    $("#reportsTo").change(function(){
        var the_selected_report = $(this).val();
        self.location = "index.php?off=&rep="+the_selected_report+"";
    });


});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<select  id="officecode" name="officecode">
  <option value="">Select an officeCode:</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="reportsTo" name="reportsTo" >
  <option value="">reports To:</option>
  <option value="1143">1143</option>
  <option value="1102">1102</option>
  <option value="1108">1108</option>
  <option value="1056">1056</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="result"><b>
<?php include "emp.php"; ?>
</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

emp.php

```
<?php

  print_r("<pre>");
  print_r($_GET);
  print_r($_POST);
  print_r("</pre>");

  /*if(isset($_GET["off"]) || isset($_GET["rep"])) {*/

    $office = $_GET["off"];
    $report = $_GET["rep"];

    $where = array();
    if(!empty($office)) { 
        $where[] = "officeCode = {$office}";
    } 

    if(!empty($report)) { 
        $where[] = "reportsTo = {$report}";
    } 


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "classicmodels";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



if($where) {
    $w = implode(" OR ", $where);   
} else {
    $w = 1;
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM employees WHERE {$w}";
print_r("<pre>");
print_r($sql);
print_r("</pre>");
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Employee Number</th>
<th>Extension</th>

</tr>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['employeeNumber'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['extension'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}

/*}*/
?>
```

[image: Empty filter]
[image: OfficeCode = 3]

Comment: it's the same there is no results the table is empty it doesn't  recognize the passed values

Comment: But reportsTo not exist in table, exist other table in your system? Or what's is reportsTo in the table?

Comment: @Glory check this example.. view data in GET when you change select and view SQL.

Comment: the same thing , still getting the same empty result , I copied and pasted your code and still the same :( reportsTo is an attribute at table employee , thank you so much for your time

Comment: uncomment the lines of sql?

Comment: I did remove the comment , here is the database that I'm using : https://app.box.com/s/0dgx2njqs1b95kuq0tn2xaeqn02v8s1o , what do you think I did wrong? thank you for your time

Comment: The index.php and emp.php works. I commented 'if' in emp.php and get all employes in first access. http://postimg.org/image/w39l60g3b/    and in this picture filter   http://postimg.org/image/miur1hwx1/

Comment: I can't thank you enough , the code is working thank you so much god bless you , thank you for your time , effort and patience

Comment: you are welcome! It is always good resolve these kinds of problems!